# Lambda function is throwing "You are not authorized to perform this operation" when trying to copy snapshots between regions

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am trying to run a test function in order to copy a single snapshot between 2 regions in AWS (in future i want to automate it). But when I run the test it throws an error

> "errorType": "ClientError",
>     "errorMessage": "An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the CopySnapshot operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation."

Here is how my IAM looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
                "ec2:ResetSnapshotAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the function:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.copy_snapshot(SourceSnapshotId='snap-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                     SourceRegion='us-central-1',
                     DestinationRegion='eu-west-3')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your policy will also need to grant `ec2:CopySnapshot` permission.

Tip: Most permissions match the name of the command they allow!

Comment: I tried with that but NO joy. THat's why i decided to paste the original JSON.

Comment: Your original JSON does not have CopySnapshot permission. Sometimes (very rarely) IAM permission takes time to replicate. Also, I don't believe us-central-1 is a valid region.

Comment: OH MY .. that's it .. wrong region .. I meant eu, not us. But still I added CopySnapshot. Thanks man!